# How can I flip that image perfectly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I found an asset pack which is kings and pigs made by PixelFrog. I was using it on unity.
As everybody knows that I have to flip the character to make him look to the other side but this dude's resolution is 78x58 pixels and he has some offset as you can see. I don't know how to fix that. He doesn't flip perfectly symmetrical. I want him to flip standing still where he was before.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

[image: Flipping issue]

[image]

I'm thinking a solution but I don't know how to do that. So what if I crop the png file in sprite editor to 58x58. I have to say that if I crop that, unity doesn't crop it perfectly as you all know. So how would I can give that gap to sprite editor to crop that image to 58x58 but at the same time image has to be at the center of that white square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I fixed it by myself just looking more carefully into that sprite editor. So I literally didnt notice that there is a padding option.

LOL. but in case someone didnt notice too, I will leave it here.
[image]